# AWS advice on fargate/ecs infrastructure for low traffic site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I want to restructure my website ([www.co2-gasp.com](http://www.co2-gasp.com) - it's a carbon capture geochemical simulator) so that it is more efficient in terms of AWS infrastructure - note that this is a *very* (5-10 visits per month) low traffic site. A primary issue is that the site runs a simulation for a visitor which requires a relatively respectable amount of memory/cpu -  1-2 cpus, 12gb memory, something like that. Note these simulations are likely only going to take a minute or so.

The current structure which is deployed through Fargate:

- An ECS Service that runs two containers, a worker and a service container
- The worker container spins up a redis server on which the jobs are run

To try and get round this problem I've tried going down the autoscalling with a cloudwatch alarm route but having some difficulty and generally think it wont work. If I provision the cluster with too low memory the job crashes  so Im thinking the autoscaling route isn't actually what I'm looking for as all it will do is spin up a new container (and the extra memory isn't going to be available for the present job).

Any thoughts on how I restructure would be super appreciated. I'm thinking I need to move the redis server to somewhere more appropriate, that can scale up to a decent amount of memory upon a job submission - then scale down again to hibernate for the next person. But how and where is just a mystery for me at the moment.

EDIT: In response to markb

I use redis-queue - see https://python-rq.org/

The code has a server.py and a worker.py file which run in the two separate containers.

The worker.py file spins up redis-queue server and looks a little like this:

```
import os
import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['default']
redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://name_of_host:6379') #remote redis

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(list(map(Queue, listen)))
        worker.work()
```

In the server.py file it handles the front end interaction which basically takes user inputs and submits the job:

```
from rq import Queue
from rq.job import Job
q = Queue(connection=conn)
job = q.enqueue(program_name, args=(a, b, c, d),job_timeout=500)
```

After I posted this question I fed my question into an chatbot and it suggested AWS Batch might be a good solution. I've got a fairly good idea about how I could restructure my code for a slurm type of submission which I would imagine AWS Batch represents.

Comment: You are correct that ECS autoscaling is not going to solve your problem. Can you explain in more detail what this "redis server" is exactly? Redis is a key/value store, so it's unclear how you are running jobs on a Redis server. The details of how that job works are really needed in order answer the question.

Comment: @MarkB hi mark, have replied in an edit in my original question. Thanks for getting back to me, appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you use redis only for queue functionality?

Comment: So it's actually a Python worker script, that pulls jobs from a Redis server. I think you could run your server.py on a very small Fargate instance, and have something (maybe in that same server script) monitor Redis for pending jobs, and spin up a separate ECS task to perform the job processing on a larger Fargate instance. Or you could switch from Redis to SQS, and then utilize SQS metrics to drive ECS auto-scaling for the job processing ECS tasks. SQS, for a low traffic site like this would basically be free, compared to the cost of a Redis host.

Answer (score 3):

From what I see on your website, I understand that there are two core parts in the overall interaction with the site:

1. Front-end application, probably single-page app, where user is able to select simulation, enter various parameters and start the job via sending HTTP request.
2. After that backend does some "magic calculations" and returns a small zip file with various results inside. The overall process takes approximately less a minute to run.

There is no any real-time client-server communication or any way to affect the in-progress calculations except starting new job.

**If the above is true**, then I think my answer below could make sense.

---

I think you might not need redis server as well as ECS at all. Since your back-end job is just a python script (or a few), requiring some noticeable amount of RAM, you may try to deploy it as [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function. I assume that you are aware of AWS Lambda, but just in case you aren't:

> Lambda is a serverless compute service, which executes your code in
> response to various events, including HTTP requests. Billing is
> calculated based on amount of executions, total duration of executions
> and selected configuration (RAM). In short words, you can execute
> computing jobs on Lambda and pay only for the resources you have used.
> Worth noting it is able to scale from 0 up to 1000 parallel executions automatically as it is a service fully managed by AWS.

So it seems an ideal execution environment for your use case. However, the maximum RAM for lambda function currently is 10GB, which I believe would be enough even despite you said that jobs usually use up to 12 GB of RAM.
Maximum execution time for Lambda is 15 minutes, which seems more than enough for your case.

I am not going to explain step-by-step how to deploy a python lambda as there are tons of such articles already. In turn, I'd like to explain a few approaches of utilising lambda in your case, starting from the simplest one.

---

## The simplest (literally no other services used except Lambda)

You front-end application sends a request with simulation parameters to a lambda function, directly via *[lambda function url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html)*.
Lambda runs calculations and responds with a file. This approach will provide the same (or even better) experience for the users as the current one on your website.

Pros: Simple to implement. Nice for prototyping and validating the overall approach. Definitely does its job for a small website with 10 monthly visitors and more.

Cons: Since API gateway is not involved, all its features are not available, for example throttling (which would definitely not be a problem for a website even with thousand monthly visitors, but you never know if/when there will be a huge traffic spike), as well as caching, validation and others.

## Simple (with API GW and S3)

This approach is quite similar. You still have a lambda function for running simulation which is triggered via HTTP request, however the request is passed via API Gateway first, enabling all the benefits of having API gateway. However, API Gateway has a duration limit for HTTP requests which is 29 seconds, meaning you won't be able to just wait while lambda runs the job, instead you have to response quickly with an id of a future zip file which will be available on AWS S3 soon. So in the the end you should have the minimal setup such as:

- API GW endpoint
- 2 Lambda Functions: one generates id for a zip file and returns it to the user as well as triggers the second lambda, which actually runs the job and saves file to S3.
  Finally, your client-side application just need to wait while file become available on S3 and download it, short-polling mechanism can be used here.

Pros: still quite simple, but already is an entry point for future, more advanced approaches. Results are collected into S3 bucket, they are accumulated there so we may reuse those later (more about this below).

Cons: To keep it simple, we need to use S3 bucket with public read access. Since the website itself is public, that is not a big issue. Otherwise we would need one more lambda and endpoint for secure access to the file (e.g. via pre-signed url).

## Better (adding cache)

The same same as previous, but instead we add a caching layer with an api gateway itself or with Cloudfront (please, google the difference and implementations yourself). Since the job executed on lambda is kinda *pure* because it returns the same result for the same set of input parameters, we may reuse already calculated results and respond immediately.
If user makes request with the input similar to input of some recent execution, API GW or Cloudfront will just return the recent response. In our case it is an ID of zip file to be fetched from S3.

Pros: Better performance of the website features. Less redundant calculations.

Cons: You need to dive deeper into cloudfront or api gw. Potentially new service to connect. Potentially will require additional handling of edge cases appearing (for example if the generated file ID has been cached, but the calculation lambda failed).

## Even Better (with SQS queue)

This is the last one in my post, but definitely not the last option in general. It is almost the same as the previous one, but one new detail is added. The aim of this detail is to make an overall solution more scalable and highly available, especially for the case when your app will eventually become popular faster than you can react to the situation.

The main idea is to add a queue (basically what you already done in your initial setup), however, with AWS SQS service instead of any self-implemented stuff. So the first lambda should not trigger the second one directly, but rather put an event into a SQS queue, which is then immediately pulled by the second one, **OR** is pulled later when the second lambda is ready to take new job (for example if there are more simultaneous requests than you allowed).

Pros: Higher availability, better handling of traffic spikes.
Cons: Slightly increased complexity.

---

### Conclusion

As you may noticed, the amount of details explained has been decreasing from one approach to another, because I aimed just to explain core ideas and assumed that after you've implemented the first one, you do not need as many details for the second... and so on.

Your website has really low traffic and even if it would increase from a dozen to few hundred users, you will still have a zero or almost zero dollars bills for AWS as I think you will not break even the monthly free [tier](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/#:%7E:text=The%20AWS%20Lambda%20free%20tier) limits. Anyway, utilising lambda for such functionality is an extremely cost-effective option (until you will have hundreds or thousands of DAILY users, who will trigger your lambda functions almost 24/7).